# specializing operator new and operator delete of some class

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator, allocator

In order to selectively trace the allocations of particular types, I have created the following construct:

```cpp
struct my_alloc {
    static void* operator new(size_t sz) { /*...*/ ; return calloc(1,sz); }
    static void operator delete(void *ptr) { /*...*/ ; return free(ptr); }
};
```

and whenever I wanted to follow the internal allocations of a particular type, say `struct A`, I could simply inherit from `my_alloc`:

```cpp
struct A : my_alloc  
{  
    AImpl* p_impl;
    A() {
        p_impl = new AImpl; // will call my_alloc::operator new
    }
    ~A() {
        delete p_impl;
    }
};

A x();  // x.p_impl has been allocated via my_alloc
```

This was also useful to trace allocations in std containers:

```cpp
using Vector = std::vector<some_class, my_alloc>;

Vector v; 
v.reserve(10);   // v.data has been allocated using my_alloc
```

However, sometimes I need to trace the allocations and I sometimes I don't.
To allow that, I tried passing the allocator as a template parameter

```cpp
template <class ALLOC>
struct A : ALLOC  {   /*...*/   };
```

but it doesn't always do the trick:

```
using A_alloced = A<my_alloc>;       // works fine
using A_non_alloced = A;             // does not does not compile
```

I also considered providing a default parameter:

```cpp
template <class ALLOC = std::allocator>
struct A : ALLOC  {   /*...*/   };
```

but I am missing std::allocator's parameter.

- **Should I change the way I parameterize `struct A` (perhaps not inherit from `my_alloc`) ? , or**
- **should I change the definition of`my_alloc` in order to achieve both the current functionality and the ability to customize `struct A` ?**

**PS:** I am looking for a formulation that would also work for the following type-erased class! Note the `new Model<B>()` call, where `Model<T>` is not visible outside the class...

```cpp
class MyType {
    struct Concept {
         virtual ~Concept() = default;
         virtual Concept* clone() const = 0;
    };

    template <class T>
    struct Model {
         T data;

         virtual Concept* clone() const { return new Model(*this); }

         template <class B> 
         Model(B value) : data(value) {}
    };

    Concept *self;
public:
    template <class B>
    MyType(B value) : self(new Model<B>(value)) {}
   
    MyType(const MyType &rhs) : self(rhs.self->clone()) { }
    
};
```

Comment: Considering your postscript, have a look at `rebind` in the standard allocators and containers to see a possible approach.

Comment: @BenVoigt, what is your favorite source on "understanding how to use allocators"? (from the perspective of the imlementer of the container).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might inherit from Empty class:

```
struct Empty{};

using A_alloced = A<my_alloc>;
using A_non_alloced = A<Empty>;
```

`allocator` might be a wrong name, especially as you wanted to subsitutes with `std::allocator`.

Comment: Embarassingly simple! Thanks!